# How do I use behavior packs for MCPE Kindle Fire version?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I imported a bunch of behavior packs into my game, and I wanted to use a specific one. I created a world and set the behavior pack to active, but the world is the exact same as it would have been before. Can anyone tell me how to get these things to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong. The behavior pack required a resource pack (textures) to work. The one I wanted was one that replaced spiders with jeeps, so it actually did replace them, it just didn't show the jeeps because I didn't have the texture pack. I have the texture pack now.